# Внести текст без тегов в тег JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Допустим, есть такой кусок html-кода:

```
<div><h3>Тут заголовок</h3><br>
Тут какой-то текст, который надо обернуть в p, например.<br>
<p>В этом же диве есть и другие элементы</p>
</div>
```

Как можно обернуть кусок текста без тегов в элемент, используя Jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое вот решение:

```
for (elements in doc.childNodes()) {
            try {
                val element: Element = Jsoup.parse(elements.outerHtml(), "", Parser.xmlParser())
                //DWTFYW
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                continue
            }
        }
```